# Number of substring using recursion

Tags: c++, recursion, data-structures

I am trying to understand recursion. I created a program to calculate number of substring in a string of n characters. Ans should be n*(n+1)/2. But for a string of 2 characters I am getting 2 as an ans and for 3 characters it is going in an infinite loop.

```
   int num_substring(string str, int &sidx, int eidx, int &num) {

       cout<<"sidx == "<<sidx<<" eidx == "<<eidx<<"num  "<<num<<endl;
       
       if(sidx >= str.length()-1) return num;  // counted all substrings

       //move starting index and start finding new substrings.
       if(eidx == str.length()-1) {
           sidx = sidx+1;
           eidx = sidx;
           cout<<"eidx reached"<<sidx<<"  "<<eidx<<endl;

       }

       for(int i = sidx; i<= eidx; i++){
         ++num;
         num_substring(str,sidx,i+1,num);
         cout<<"sidx after "<<sidx<<endl;
       }

       return 0;

    }


    int main()
    {
        string str = "ab";
        int num = 0;
        int sidx = 0;
        num_substring(str,sidx,0,num);
        cout<<num<<endl;
    }
```

Output is

```
sidx == 0 eidx == 0num  0
sidx == 0 eidx == 1num  1
eidx reached1  1
sidx == 1 eidx == 2num  2
sidx after 1 ---> why is sidx 1? Shouldnt it be 0
sidx after 1
2
```

Comment: Did you try debugging it?

Comment: Should `sidx` perhaps be non-reference here?

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk Yes tried debugging but couldnt figure out.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know this algorithm. Please explain how it should work.

Comment: @user968000 Can you please share some sample input/output for your problem?

Comment: The line "num_substring(str,sidx,i+1,num);" is a recursion invocation, BUT, the return value (an integer) is discarded.